# Ionic: $scope change not reflected on the page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

On my Ionic App, I have a view that has a button. When you click on the button, a list of player would be served in a modal, when clicked on a player name, the name of the selected player should be shown on the page and the button should be hidden.
Here's the codepen for the same - http://codepen.io/mradul/pen/vNywqG
However, when I select a value(player name) on the modal, the scope variable gets updated(as it's printed on the console), but the change is not reflected on the page. 
HTML -

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-positive bar-header">
    <h1 class="title">Selected Player</h1>
</ion-header-bar>

<ion-content>


    <script id="select-player.html" type="text/ng-template">
        <div class="modal">
            <ion-header-bar>
                <h1 class="title">Choose Player</h1>
            </ion-header-bar>
            <ion-content>
                <ion-list>
                    <ion-item ng-repeat="player in getPlayerList().players"  ng-click="closeModal(player)">
                       {{player}}
                    </ion-item>
                </ion-list>
            </ion-content>
        </div>
    </script>


    <br/><br/>
    <div id="player">
      {{sc.player}}
        <div class="row">
        <a class="button" ng-click="openModal()" ng-show="sc.player.playerName == null">Set player</a>
        <div ng-hide="sc.player.playerName  == null">
            <div class="col col-33 "   > {{sc.player.playerName}}</div>

        </div>


</ion-content>
```

JS -

```
angular.module('ionicApp',['ionic']).controller('scoringController', function ($scope,  $ionicModal) {

   $scope.player = {playerName:""};

$scope.getPlayerList = function () {
    console.log("getting player list");
    return {
        "players": [
  "Mradul",
  "JAin",
  "Phunsuk Wangdu",
  "Hulk"
        ]
    };
};

$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('select-player.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
}).then(function (modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal
})

$scope.openModal = function () {

    console.log("Setting model open ");
    $scope.modal.show()
}

$scope.closeModal = function (playerName) {

    $scope.player.playerName = playerName;
    //$scope.activePlayers[0] = playerName;
    console.log("Player Set ", $scope);
    console.log("model closed");
    $scope.modal.hide();

};

$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    $scope.modal.remove();
});
```

});

Player was initially a primitive(string), but I changed it into an object by having a property - playerName. May be I didn't do it right. Please suggest how can I have the parent scope variable updated correctly. I might have missed something very basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, Am not sure about it

```
 {{player.playerName}}
```

Comment: It worked. I had this line - <ion-view ng-controller="scoringController as sc"> at the top of the html code, which is not showing up in the question. I had aliased sc as the controller. So was trying to access the scope variables using sc.variableName. I think I'd just get rid of 'as sc'. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Write $scope.$apply() after your change

Comment: I had tried it earlier, but it gave an error. Something like 'scope already applied'